# Converting an image sequence with an alpha channel to video and keeping the transparency

Tags: video-sequence-editor, transparency

I've checked the related questions, but the last similar question was asked 7 years ago. I haven't done video editing before (so please treat me as a noob in this field), and wasn't doing 3D art back then, so I don't know what's changed, if anything, with regards to blender's video editing tools.

Before finding out that my attempt to make the conversion failed, I tried the ffmpeg format and used the MPEG-4 and Quicktime containers in separate attempts. I used the H.264 for the MPEG-4 and HuffYUV for the Quicktime formats respectively. The MPEG-4 video plays with a black background (which I can't tell whether it's got an alpha channel or not), and the Quicktime video was a complete mess with no visuals of my animation at all.

As far as I can tell, I need a video format which supports alpha channels, but it doesn't seem like blender has that capability. Please tell me if I'm wrong, or if I'm right, what I need to do to make the conversion.

Sorry for the long post, I wasn't really sure what was relevant to include, so I just included everything I did. I appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that when you add your image sequence to the video sequencer (VSE), you see a checkerboard background for the transparent regions? If so, you can render this out as a video file with the transparency conserved by choosing the correct codec (see also the comment of duplicate post). Which codec. The key is to pay attention to the color attribute of the Output panel. There are two possibilities: RGB or RGBA. The latter is a codec that supports transparency. In the first screenshot, I have chosen for the FFmpeg Video file format, the Matroska container and the PNG video codec. This is a codec that supports transparency. The second screenshot with the MPEG-4 and H.264 codec does not support transparency. You can tell it because the A-option in RGBA is not available.

You can test this very easily by rendering out the sequence and adding back the previous output file to the sequencer. You should see a checkerboard.

[image: codec with transparency]

[image: codec without transparency]